# modes not showing in status bar of vim

Tags: linux-mint, vim, vimrc

I installed vim version 7.4.1689 in my linux mint 18. I opened any file with vim but after switching between modes on the status bar it is not showing anything like which mode I am currently in. I searched everywhere for the solution found one but it did not worked. The solution given was to use the command:

`:set showmode`
[image: this is my insert mode]

in `/.vimrc` file, I did that but nothing happened, can somebody please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What's the answer to `:scriptnames` and `:set showmode?` ?

Comment: I did not get you? Can you please say clearly?

Comment: In Vim, enter the commands `:scriptnames` and `:set showmode?`. They should list the names of the scripts which have been sources and the current state of the `showmode` option. What do those commands return?

Comment: :scriptsnames - returned a list of scripts

Comment: And :set showmode returned - "showmode"

Comment: Liike this shown after :scriptnames:1 : /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim

Comment: Your `~/.vimrc` file is not in the list. Are you sure that you put the `.vimrc` file in your home directory?

Comment: ya i have included that in the list and its shown by this command,due to word restriction i did not posted that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will work

```
:set laststatus=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning off bold color option from profile under text tab.

Otherwise use

```
:set showmode
```